# OpenGL multiple render target FBO with multisampling - requirements

Tags: opengl, fbo, multisampling

When creating a multisample FBO, do all attached target textures need to be multisample-textures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Section 9.4.2 Whole Framebuffer Completeness](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf) of the spec states:

> The framebuffer object bound to target is said to be framebuffer complete if all
>   the following conditions are true:
>   [...]
>
> • The value of `RENDERBUFFER_SAMPLES` is the same for all attached renderbuffers; the value of `TEXTURE_SAMPLES` is the same for all attached textures; and, if the attached images are a mix of renderbuffers and textures,
>   the value of `RENDERBUFFER_SAMPLES` matches the value of `TEXTURE_SAMPLES`.

So yes, the number of samples has to be the same for all attached textures and renderbuffers.

Answer (score 2):

I *think* so.

> **§ 9.2.3.1 Multisample Queries**
>
> The values of `SAMPLE_BUFFERS` and `SAMPLES` control whether and how multisampling is performed (...).
>
> If a framebuffer object is not framebuffer complete (...), then the values of `SAMPLE_BUFFERS` and `SAMPLES` are undefined.
>
> Otherwise, the value of `SAMPLES` is equal to the value of `RENDERBUFFER_SAMPLES` or `TEXTURE_SAMPLES` (depending on the type of the attached images), which **must all have the same value**.

(emphasis mine)